# I have an issue in union all query while pagination with the Limit

Tags: php, mysql

With this query it show me all `featured=1` records on first page and then on second they all disapear.

```
$sql = "(select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '1') LIMIT 5)
       UNION ALL (select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '0') LIMIT 5) LIMIT 0,10 ";
```

I wanted to display 5 records of `featured=1` and 5 records of `featured=0` It is having the issue with the last Limit I think because when i remove the Limit at the end It show me all records of `featured=1` on all pages but there occur a problem with the inner limits.

```
echo $sql = "(select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '1') LIMIT 5)
             UNION ALL (select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '0') LIMIT 5) ";
```

Comment: how it will be displayed with second option ?

Comment: 5 records of featured and 5 of premium. the featured=1 are featured and featured=0 in database are premium records

Comment: echo $sql = "(select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '1') LIMIT 5)
             UNION ALL (select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '0') LIMIT 5) "  . $pagination->getLimitSql();

Comment: Where  . $pagination->getLimitSql(); is Limit 0,10 and on the second page it is Limit 10,10 on third it is 20,10 and so on. whether If i  remove this . $pagination->getLimitSql(); the records all would be displayed with changing of manual search.php?page=1 or any like search.php?page=3 or any it works perfect but until i would never have limit 0,10 or any it will hide pagination buttons i think the limit issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 5 records of `featured = '1'` and union them with 5 records of `featured = '0'`, following query do this :

```
(select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '1') LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL 
(select * from `property` where (`city`='33') AND (`featured` = '0') LIMIT 5)
```